# Best way to integrate contact us page with wordpress REST API

Tags: api, plugin-contact-form-7

I want to integrate contact us page on my site. I am using Angular for frontend and WP-REST api.

I want to capture Fullname, email, subject and Message but I am wondering what is the suitable way to capture those fields using WP-REST API?

Comment: @MarkKaplun, Actually, I didn't try anything yet because I am wondering how can I achieve this.

Comment: There is not much point in asking open ended questions without even trying to give them context

Comment: Can I create custom post to handle those fields?

Comment: Get and create posts is one of the main (I would say the "main") purpose of the REST API, So, of course you can create a custom post to handle those fields if you want. You could start by [reading documentation](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/) and come back if you have problems to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks @cybmeta. I think I got my answer. I just want to know is that right way to handle contact us data or not. :)